# Why it is reflecting undefined in Mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongoDb and took one course but stuck at this point .I created this Index.js and here I'm inserting one data and using callbacks but after insertion it is reflecting undefined?

```
--indes.js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const dbname = 'conFusion';

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
    assert.equal(err, null);

    console.log('Connected correctly to server');

    const db = client.db(dbname);
    const collection = db.collection('dishes');
    collection.insertOne({ "name": "Uthappizza1", "description": "test" },
        (err, result) => {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log('After Insert:\n');
        console.log(result.ops);

        collection.find({}).toArray((err, docs) => {
            assert.equal(err, null);

            console.log('Found:\n');
            console.log(docs);

            db.dropCollection('dishes', (err, result) => {
                assert.equal(err, null);

                client.close();
            });
        });
    });
});
 also attaching the package.json for more clearilty

{
  "name": "node-mongo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node MongoDB Example",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index"
  },
  "author": "Shivam Singh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

I'm also attaching the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `insertOne` method through the callback returns object of interface [InsertOneResult](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/interfaces/insertoneresult.html), which according to the documentation only has 2 fields: `acknowledged` and `insertedId`. Due to this reason `result.ops` will always be `undefined` here because you do have `result` object, but it doesn't have the property `ops`.

Comment: Instead of logging "result.ops" in the callback, log "results" and see the fields that you're getting (should be "acknowledged" and "insertedId"). If you wish to use any of these fields, go ahead.